# ¿Cómo puedo diferenciar el valor de un radio en PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo un problema, no puedo recoger los datos de unos inputs radio, es decir, quiero recoger el value en una base pero no se registran, estoy utilizando `phpmailer` y `ajax` por `post`.

Lo único que quiero es que se pueda recoger el value de los inputs radio para ponerlo en una base de datos.

Este es el formulario:

```
     <div class="form-row justify-content-md-center my-5">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mb-3 mx-4">
               <input type="radio" id="RadioSolucion1" name="RadioSolucion" value="home-office" class="custom-control-input" required>
               <label class="custom-control-label" for="RadioSolucion1">
                    Casa u Oficina
               </label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mb-3 mx-4">
               <input type="radio" id="RadioSolucion2" name="RadioSolucion" value="corp" class="custom-control-input" required>
               <label class="custom-control-label" for="RadioSolucion2">
                    Empresarial
               </label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mb-3 mx-4">
               <input type="radio" id="RadioSolucion3" name="RadioSolucion" value="industrial" class="custom-control-input" required>
               <label class="custom-control-label" for="RadioSolucion3">
                    Industrial
               </label>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Este es mi PHP:

```
<?php
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

 require 'src/Exception.php';
 require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
 require 'src/SMTP.php';
 // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
 $radio= $_POST["radio"];
 $name  = $_POST["name"];
 $email = $_POST["email"]; 
 $company = $_POST["company"];
 $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];   
 $sector = $_POST["sector"];
 $number = $_POST["number"];
 $message = $_POST["message"];
 $solucion = $_POST["solucion"];

 $website = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
 $website = dirname($website);
 $website = dirname($website);

 $msg     = "Saludos
           <br/>
           Ha recibido un mensaje del formulario de contacto desde Google Adwords.
           <br/>
           <br>Este e-mail fue enviado desde un formulario de contacto en $website";
```

Comment: los unicos valores que puede tener un radio es un ´true o false (1 o 0)´

Comment: @JuanL falso.. https://www.anerbarrena.com/value-radio-button-jquery-checked-1580/

Comment: coloca el código Ajax que tienes, para ver como envías los datos.

Comment: Haz un var_dump($_POST) para salir de dudas sobre lo que envías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo tienes casi: estás leyendo una variable de entorno llamada `radio` cuando según tu código debería llamarse `RadioSolucion`.  En cada uno de los botones de radio tienes este código:

```
<input type="radio" id="RadioSolucion1" name="RadioSolucion" value="home-office" class="custom-control-input" required>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

y cuando haces un POST envías el parámetro especificado en el `name` de la botonera. Si rodeo tu código con una etiqueta `form` y selecciono el primer resultado, lo que el navegador manda por POST es:

```
RadioSolucion=home-office&boton=submit
```

, es decir, que para que funcione tienes que cambiar:

```
[...]
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
$radio = $_POST["RadioSolucion"];  <<<<<
$name  = $_POST["name"];
[...]
```

Comment: No especificas porque debe llamarse `RadioSolucion`, aunque ademas esto es valido cuando el envío es por `submit` de un `<form>`. El OP en su pregunta dice que realiza el envío por `AJAX`

Comment: Creí que era absolutamente obvio el error, pero por si acaso no quedaba claro, he ampliado la solución. Sobre el otro comentario, el usuario especifica que la consulta llega en un POST (que sea asíncrona o no es irrelevante, pues como puedes ver está leyendo `$_POST`).

Comment: Solucionado con la respuesta de @Ender, muchas gracias, sólo era cambiar los ID´s.

Comment: Perfecto. ¿Podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta?